# AES 256 encryption in .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, aes, .net-2.0

Does anyone know if C# can be used in .NET Framework 2.0 to use AES 256 encryption and decryption? Appreciate if the in-built framework supports this or if we have to use any external APIs for the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. It contains classes you can use for AES encryption, such as the `Rijndael` class.

Answer (score 5):

It's built in - you need to use the [`Rijndael Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=VS.80).aspx) (the name of the algorithm which won the [NIST AES competition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard_process)) in [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

Comment: <Pedantic> "Rijndael" is *not* the "Offical" name for AES, but the name of the algorithm from which the AES standard was created (mostly by not allowing many of the Rijndael options for key length etc..

Comment: See here for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx

Comment: @Richard: Lol I edited this as you wrote it. I type a quick answer first then correct it, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: you always need to watch for race conditions, even when you don't expect them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Before it won the title of AES it was called Rijndael. Support for the [Rijndael class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx) has been in .Net since version 1.0.